# Reusing a where array

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Say I needed to do a whole bunch of queries from various tables like so

```
var weights = db.weights.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ItemId)).Select(x => x.weight).ToList();
var heights = db.heights.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ItemId)).Select(x => x.height).ToList();
var lengths = db.lengths.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ItemId)).Select(x => x.length).ToList();
var widths  = db.widths.Where( x => ids.Contains(x.ItemId)).Select(x => x.width ).ToList();
```

Okay, its really not that stupid in reality but its just for illustrating the question. Basically, that array "ids" gets sent to the database 4 times in this example. I was thinking I could save some bandwidth by just sending it once. Is it possible to do that? Sorta like

```
db.SetTempVariable("ids", ids);
var weights = db.weights.Where(x => db.TempVariable["ids"].Contains(x.ItemId)).Select(x => x.weight).ToList();
var heights = db.heights.Where(x => db.TempVariable["ids"].Contains(x.ItemId)).Select(x => x.height).ToList();
var lengths = db.lengths.Where(x => db.TempVariable["ids"].Contains(x.ItemId)).Select(x => x.length).ToList();
var widths  = db.widths.Where( x => db.TempVariable["ids"].Contains(x.ItemId)).Select(x => x.width ).ToList();
db.DeleteTempVariable("ids");
```

I'm just imagining the possible syntax here. In essence, SetTempVariable would send the data to the database and db.TempVariables["ids"] would be just like a dummy object to use in expressions that really only contains a reference to previously sent data and then the database magically understands this and reuses the list of ids i sent it instead of me sending it again and again.

So, how can I do that?

Comment: What you would really need to do is create one query that gets all the values you need.  However that would be messy and I'd only attempt it if this is truly a bottleneck in the code.

Comment: You can try to use Union method ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.union?view=net-5.0 ) for make required operation

Comment: I'm gonna say "no" because you're querying different tables. Optimize something else..

Comment: As people say. EF is not a good choice for such databases. What you need here is temporary tables. So better search for alternatives, for example `linq2db`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is more a database design problem than anything. A properly designed database would have one table that contains weights, heights, lengths and widths for every item (or "id" as you call it), so one query on the item returns everything at once.

I'm reluctant to suggest bandaid fixes for the broken database design you're using, because you really should just fix that, but you'll find a large improvement in performance if you open a transaction first and run all 4 of your queries in it. Or just join the tables on `id` (they seem the same?), and then your queries become one query.

To answer your actual question, and again you're barking up the wrong tree here, that's what temp tables are. You can upload your data to a temp table and then join it against your other table(s).

Comment: There is no fixing this database as it contains a decade of legacy data and according to my project manager "its good enough, don't touch it because nobody knows how to fix it if it breaks".

Comment: "Legacy" just means bad, and data quantity doesn't make things harder to fix. I would suggest making a complete and correct migration plan, explain clearly why it's better than what you have and then show it to your manager.

Comment: I am strongly suggesting you do this before trying to use your database through EF. Especially the legacy version of EF you seem to be using, EF6. EF isn't a general purpose ORM, it has a lot of conventions that apply to correctly normalized relational database patterns, and what you ran into is just one example. You need proper foreign keys for relational properties to work, proper indices for the completely automated queries to work, the correct "is-a" pattern for deriving classes to work, the correct layout for many-to-many relations, etc.